# What are the problems associated with destroying the controller without the options used while generating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, destroy

I have created a controller(with lots of options like --no-helper, ...) in Rails two months back using the command

```
rails generate controller <ControllerName> --no-options
```

Now, I want to cleanup that controller completely. But, I forget those options set at that time.

My question is if I run,

```
 rails destroy controller <ControllerName>
```

without the options that were specified before will it clear all the files related to this controller?

My second question is,

Is there any log in rails that contains all the commands that were run for the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rails destroy` command will "figure out what generate did" (according to the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-destroy)) and undo it. So the answer is no, you **don't** have to specify the options you used when you ran `rails generate`.

Also, you can use the `-p, [--pretend]` parameter while running `rails destroy` to do a dry run and see what changes the command will make. Actually that is the more sensible thing to do.

As for your second question, there is no such log.